# Can an anonymous function return itself?

Tags: php, lambda, return, anonymous-function

In some PHP quiz I got the following task - I have to `return true` on the following:

```
function foo($x)
{
    return $x === $x();
}

foo(__________ALLOWED_INPUT____________);
```

Now my idea was to pass an anonymous function which returns itself:

```
foo(function() { return $this_function; })
```

However I did not yet figure out a way to do this. Is it possible somehow?

PS: Nice Game (https://returntrue.win/?level=6).

Comment: I'd have thought a named function that returns its own name would do the trick?

Comment: @Spudley I thought that too - until I tried it out, got `
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function foo(), 0 passed`

Comment: You can return a reference to the function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create an anonymous function that returns a reference to itself:

```
foo($x=function()use(&$x){return$x;})
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/743f72c298e81e70f13dc0892894911adfb1b072

Comment: I think his goal is to get it returning true just by changing the input?

Comment: Just one more clarification such that is satisfies the question completely: It is not possible for an anonymous function to return itself without it having a reference to itself?

Comment: No, it must be a reference @Blackbam. Not sure how returning the function without a reference is valuable.

Answer (score 2):

[Whitespace is for readability only; all of these should work on one line if required.]

As a variation on [Alexandre Elshobokshy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048256/157957), you could use a (super-)global variable instead of a `use` statement to give the function access to itself:

```
foo(
    $GLOBALS['x'] = function() { 
        return $GLOBALS['x']; 
    }
);
```

Or you could let the function find itself in the call stack using [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace):

```
foo(
    function() { 
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
        return $backtrace[1]['args'][0];
    }
)
```

Inspired by a comment from Spudley about returning a function name, you can actually declare a function within the scope allowed by wrapping it in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression):

```
foo(
    (function(){
       function f(){ return 'f'; }
       return 'f';
    })()
);
```

Comment: Interesting options! The third one is immediatly executed though and returning the result, this is not the same as returning a reference right?

Comment: @Blackbam The IIFE is just a way of defining the function `f` within the space given; what's actually run is `foo('f');`. Returning the string `f` is indeed not the same as returning a reference, though, it's a slightly different approach to the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous function cannot return a reference to itself as far as I know, and there is no built-in PHP function that returns a reference to itself as far as I know, so that would leave an invokable class. That could work:

```
new class{function __invoke(){return $this;}}
```

[answers-to-returntrue.win-with-explanations](https://www.rpkamp.com/2018/02/15/all-answers-to-returntrue.win-with-explanations/)